# TableView's textLabel height according to content

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have made an Collapsed TableView. The size of the tableView's label is not increasing according the content. I had set WordWrap and Lines = 0 but still it's not working.
I'm using 2 tableView cell's to make the collapsed view.

```
extension UIView {
func rotate(toValue: CGFloat, duration: CFTimeInterval = 0.2, completionDelegate: AnyObject? = nil) {
    let rotateAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
    rotateAnimation.toValue = toValue
    rotateAnimation.duration = duration
    rotateAnimation.removedOnCompletion = false
    rotateAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards

    if let delegate: AnyObject = completionDelegate {
        rotateAnimation.delegate = delegate
    }
    self.layer.addAnimation(rotateAnimation, forKey: nil)
}
}

class CollapsibleTableViewController: UITableViewController {
struct Section {
    var name: String!
    var items: [String]!
    var collapsed: Bool!

    init(name: String, items: [String], collapsed: Bool = false) {
        self.name = name
        self.items = items
        self.collapsed = collapsed
    }
}

var sections = [Section]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    sections = [Section(name: "TEXT OVER HERE", items: ["TEXT OVER HERE."])]
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return sections.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return (sections[section].collapsed!) ? 0 : sections[section].items.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let header = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("header") as! CollapsibleTableViewHeader

    header.toggleButton.tag = section
    header.titleLabel.text = sections[section].name
    header.toggleButton.rotate(sections[section].collapsed! ? 0.0 : CGFloat(M_PI_2))
    header.toggleButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CollapsibleTableViewController.toggleCollapse), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    return header.contentView
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell!

    cell.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
    cell.textLabel?.text = sections[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row]



    return cell
}

//
// MARK: - Event Handlers
//
func toggleCollapse(sender: UIButton) {
    let section = sender.tag
    let collapsed = sections[section].collapsed

    // Toggle collapse
    sections[section].collapsed = !collapsed

    // Reload section
    tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: section), withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
}

}
```

[image]

Comment: are you used autolayout or autoresizing in your project

Comment: Yes, I have used AutoLayout but not for the Label's. I have used it on FirstCell's(i.e 'header') Button which shows collapsing. The second Cell is completely blank.

Comment: see this https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/32/2/automatically-resizing-uitableviewcells-with-dynamic-type-and-ns

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

    var lblSectionName: UILabel = UILabel()
    lblSectionName.text = self.sectionNames[section]
    lblSectionName.numberOfLines = 0
    lblSectionName.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping
    lblSectionName.sizeToFit()
    return lblSectionName.frame.size.height
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    var lblSectionName: UILabel = UILabel()
    lblSectionName.text = self.sectionNames[section]
    lblSectionName.numberOfLines = 0
    lblSectionName.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping
    lblSectionName.sizeToFit()
    return lblSectionName
}
```

Comment: I tried that already after reading Anbu.Karthik's comment, but after that only the Collapsed cell's textLabel's height is getting fixed. The header textLabel's height remains same as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Better is this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29763200/1054550

```
self.tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
self.tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 25;
```