# Two headers in ViewForHeaderInSection

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want two headers at the top of the view controller that does not disappear as the table is scrolled.

The first section of code displays a top header that I have in `viewDidLoad`. The `viewForHeaderInSection` works correctly. How do I add the header to the `viewForHeaderInSection`?

```
let header =  UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 100))
header.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
//header.addSubview(header)
tableView.tableHeaderView = header

/////////

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let v = UIView()
    v.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    let segmentControl = UISegmentedControl(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 5, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 30))
    segmentControl.insertSegment(withTitle: "one", at: 0, animated: false)
    segmentControl.insertSegment(withTitle: "two", at: 1, animated: false)
    segmentControl.insertSegment(withTitle: "three", at: 2, animated: false)
    v.addSubview(segmentControl)
    return v
}
```

Comment: Do you want 2 views added together in **one** viewForHeader? Or you want 1 header for each section and 1 header for *entire* tableview?

Comment: I want two views added together in one viewForHeader. Thank you

Comment: in `v` you can add two subviews 1) your segment control 2) red view

Answer (score 0):

Just add one view (segmentControl) as a subview of another view (v). And then return that as your view for the viewForHeaderInSection. You have to use [constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26180822/swift-adding-constraints-programmatically) between `segmentControl` & `v` instances.

And don't forget, for the `segmentControl` you must set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false`. However you should [NOT set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47800210/when-should-translatesautoresizingmaskintoconstraints-be-set-to-true) for the `v` instance, because you don't manage the outer constraints for that, the tableview will do it for you...

Answer (score 0):

I think this helpful to you:

//Your Tableview

```
@IBOutlet var tblviewSideMenu: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {  

    super.viewDidLoad()

    let screenSize: CGRect = tblviewSideMenu.frame

    let myView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenSize.width,height: 145))
    myView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 88.0/255.0, blue: 181.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

    tblviewSideMenu.addSubview(myView)
    tblviewSideMenu.tableHeaderView = myView
    tblviewSideMenu .reloadData()
    tblviewSideMenu.tableFooterView = UIView()     
 }
```

Note: if you want two headers add one more view