# Mysterious value introduced by NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint set by AutoLayout system

Tags: ios, autolayout, storyboard, nslayoutconstraint

AutoLayout is adding a NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint that causes a conflict, and it's unclear where and how.

The question is: where does the height of 293 come from?

UIView hierarchy:

[image]

The AutoLayout log has been numbered. Xcode labels didn't show up in the AutoLayout logs.

Line 1 seems to be the trouble. Based on the constraints, it seems this is `Post View Cell`, which is a custom `UICollectionViewCell`.

Yet the `sizeForItemAt` UICollectionViewDelegate function does not return this value. If you hard code the return value to something like `CGSize(width: 300, height: 100)`, 293 still appears in the log.

So where is 293 coming from?

Line 2 is a constraint set in code, and this is the right value. This view should be `Attachment View`.

Lines 3 & 4 refer to `Post Content View`, which is a `UIStackView`.

Line 5 refers to the `Text View`.

Line 6 refers to `Attachment View`.

Line 7 is the spacing set by the `UIStackView` (`Post Content View`).

```
1. "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x600002a47610 h=--& v=--& UIView:0x7facf0e126b0.height == 293   (active)>",
2. "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002a79a40 UIView:0x7facf0e07110.height == 280   (active)>",
3. "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002a785a0 V:[UIStackView:0x7facf0e12890]-(10)-|   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7facf0e126b0 )>",
4. "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002a79180 V:|-(10)-[UIStackView:0x7facf0e12890]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7facf0e126b0 )>",
5. "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002a7cff0 'UISV-canvas-connection' UIStackView:0x7facf0e12890.top == UITextView:0x7facf283a600'hi'.top   (active)>",
6. "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002a7cf00 'UISV-canvas-connection' V:[UIView:0x7facf0e07110]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':UIStackView:0x7facf0e12890 )>",
7. "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002a7d270 'UISV-spacing' V:[UITextView:0x7facf283a600'hi']-(5)-[UIView:0x7facf0e07110]   (active)>"


Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002a79a40 UIView:0x7facf0e07110.height == 280   (active)>
```

Comment: Hey @crashalot, Did you find a solution for this? I'm facing a similar problem

Answer (score 2):

An NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint can arise any time you have a view for which `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` is `true` (which, unfortunately, is the default when you create a view in code). Make sure that that's not the case.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Yes, we checked this condition already. Is there another potential cause?

Comment: Without details on how to reproduce the problem, I can't be more specific, sorry. You can get full information on how the constraints were created by using Instruments, or, easier, you can see what's at the heart of the conflict by using the View Debugger.

Comment: OK will try to simplify problem and post code to reproduce issue. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. View Debugger would show when AutoLayout creates NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint constraint?

Comment: Also if adding view2 to view1,  we only need to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false` for view2, right? Not both view1 and view2.

Comment: On the contrary if adding view 2 to view 1 with constraints, view 1 becomes entangled in autolayout so its settings become important.

Comment: So set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to false for both view1 and view2?