# Custom created views size is not changing based on the constraints

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder

I have build a custom view that needs to be embedded at various places.

Here is what I did along with the code:

1) Created a Swift file and an xib file called CustomLabel. Contents of CustomLabel.swift:

```
import UIKit

class CustomLabel: UIView {

@IBOutlet var view: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    print("CustomLabel")
    Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomLabel", owner: self, options: nil)


    self.addSubview(self.view)
}



}
```

Here is how CustomLabel.xib looks:

[image: I have made the size]

I have made the view freeform and set its height. I have added a label view inside it with constraints on all four sides.

Now I am adding this view to my Main ViewController but setting the width of this view to be bigger than the original reusable view.

This is the result:

[image]

The yellow background shows the extra width of the view and the black one is the original view.

**How do I make sure that the reusable view is stretched to cover the whole view?**

Comment: When views are layed out prorgrammatically this is often an issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47800210/when-should-translatesautoresizingmaskintoconstraints-be-set-to-true

Comment: @Teetz setting translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false it making the view cover even smaller portion of the whole view.

Comment: you could also for example set it to true and give your view a flexibleWidth autoresizing mask. this should just be a hint in the right direction - not a "do this" option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are loading your XIB creates ***two*** `UIView` objects, where you may be thinking it creates only one.

You can easily see this using `Debug View Hierarchy`

Here, the Blue view is the view added to Storyboard, with constraints set normally (in this case, 40-pts from each side, height of 100, and centered vertically).

The Red view is the view you work with when designing your XIB, and it has a label with black background, constrained to `0` on all four sides.

[image]

Your XIB **class** is `UIView` -- so it is its *own* view... When you added a `UIView` to your storyboard and set its class to `CustomLabel`, that becomes the "root" view. In your code, you are **adding** `view` as a subview... which should give you the clue that you now have **two** `UIView` objects.

What's happened now is that the `CustomLabel` itself (which is a `UIView`) uses the constraints you set in storyboard, but the `view` subview does *not* have constraints set.

If you change your loading code to this (I changed your `IBOutlet` names, because adding "view" as a subview to another "view" can become very confusing):

```
class CustomLabel: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var theView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var thelabel: UILabel!

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        print("CustomLabel")
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomLabel", owner: self, options: nil)

        self.addSubview(self.theView)

        self.theView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            self.theView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            self.theView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            self.theView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            self.theView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            ])

    }

}
```

Now, your code loads the view from the XIB, adds it as a subview of `CustomLabel` (which, again, is a `UIView` itself), and sets up the constraints as you'd expect, giving this result:

[image]

As you can see, `theView` which has been added as a subview (red in this image), is now constrained to its superview - the blue `CustomLabel`.