# How add vertical button list from top right corner programmatically in Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift

I need to add buttons from top right corner of the screen. I have added buttons. it is working fine in iPhone. But when I run to iPad it start on middle right corner of the screen. I have use below code..

```
 let button1 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: view.frame.size.width - 56, y: view.frame.size.width - 220, width: 30, height: 30))
  self.view.addSubview(button1)

 let button12 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: view.frame.size.width - 56, y: view.frame.size.width - 150, width: 30, height: 30))
 self.view.addSubview(button12)
```

How to add button from top right corner always both phone or iPad?

Comment: Maybe try using auto layout constraints?

Comment: @ParthibBiswas sir I have used in google map

Comment: Use constraints!

Comment: @DonMag how to add constraint here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `view.frame.size.width` to a static value for `y` position. Because UIView position calculation starts from **Top-Left** corner.

```
let button1 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: view.frame.size.width - 56, y: 20, width: 30, height: 30))
self.view.addSubview(button1)

let button12 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: view.frame.size.width - 56, y: 60, width: 30, height: 30))
self.view.addSubview(button12)
```

If you want to add **AutoLayoutConstraint** try this

```
let button1 = UIButton()
button1.setTitle("Button 1", for: .normal)
button1.backgroundColor = .red
button1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
 self.view.addSubview(button1)

let button12 = UIButton()
button12.setTitle("Button 12", for: .normal)
button12.backgroundColor = .red
button12.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
self.view.addSubview(button12)

button1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
button1.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
button1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
button1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true

button12.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button1.bottomAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
button12.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
button12.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
button12.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
```

To know about `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` please check it - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47800210/when-should-translatesautoresizingmaskintoconstraints-be-set-to-true)

Answer (score 0):

I would look into adding these directly to a storyboard. Possibly create these two buttons in a stackview. If you need go programmatically, the main issue with your above example is to use `height` instead of `width` for `y`:

```
let button1 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.frame.size.width - 56, y: self.view.frame.size.height - 220, width: 30, height: 30))
self.view.addSubview(button1)

let button12 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.frame.size.width - 56, y: self.view.frame.size.height - 150, width: 30, height: 30))
self.view.addSubview(button12)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pin your buttons with constraints to that view like that:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    self.button1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: *first button top margin*),
    self.button1.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor, constant: *first button right margin*),
    self.button2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.button1.bottomAnchor, constant: *second button top margin*),
    self.button2.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor, constant: *second button right margin*)
])
```

Do not forget to add subviews like you did `self.view.addSubview(button1)`
You can also set constraints for width and height.

Apple docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ProgrammaticallyCreatingConstraints.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH16-SW1