# How to separate Views into smaller ones in programmatic UIKit?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uikit

I'm. trying to make my code cleaner by separating my code into smaller files. When I have a single ViewController, it works! However, when I try to add a subview, it doesn't. Can anyone look at my code and tell me what's wrong?

### Code:

#### ViewController (just view controller, when it works):

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private let textField = UITextField()

    override func loadView() {
        let view = UIView()
        self.view = view
        let textField = UITextField()
        textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(textField)
        view.addConstraint(textField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor))
        view.addConstraint(textField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor))
        view.addConstraint(textField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor))
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        textField.becomeFirstResponder()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .red
    }
}
```

[image: iOS Simulator 1]

#### ViewController (when trying to add the subview)

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let searchViewController = SearchViewController()
        
        view.addSubview(searchViewController.view)
    }
}
```

#### SearchViewController

```swift
import UIKit

class SearchViewController: UIViewController {
    private let textField = UITextField()

    override func loadView() {
        let view = UIView()
        self.view = view
        let textField = UITextField()
        textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(textField)
        view.addConstraint(textField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor))
        view.addConstraint(textField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor))
        view.addConstraint(textField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor))
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        textField.becomeFirstResponder()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .red
    }
}
```

#### SceneDelegate (additional file to show you that I successfully removed storyboards and make a programmatic UIKit available)

```swift
import UIKit

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
        // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
        // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
        guard let scene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        
        window = UIWindow(windowScene: scene)
        window?.rootViewController = ViewController()
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }

    func sceneDidDisconnect(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called as the scene is being released by the system.
        // This occurs shortly after the scene enters the background, or when its session is discarded.
        // Release any resources associated with this scene that can be re-created the next time the scene connects.
        // The scene may re-connect later, as its session was not necessarily discarded (see `application:didDiscardSceneSessions` instead).
    }

    func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called when the scene has moved from an inactive state to an active state.
        // Use this method to restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) when the scene was inactive.
    }

    func sceneWillResignActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called when the scene will move from an active state to an inactive state.
        // This may occur due to temporary interruptions (ex. an incoming phone call).
    }

    func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called as the scene transitions from the background to the foreground.
        // Use this method to undo the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func sceneDidEnterBackground(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called as the scene transitions from the foreground to the background.
        // Use this method to save data, release shared resources, and store enough scene-specific state information
        // to restore the scene back to its current state.
    }


}
```

[image: iOS Simulator 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When adding a child view controller you are always required to call [addChild(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621394-addchild) on the parent VC and [didMove(toParent:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621405-didmove) on the child VC.

```swift
let searchViewController = SearchViewController()
addChild(searchViewController)
searchViewController.didMove(toParent: self)
view.addSubview(searchViewController.view)
```

But the most important thing is that you are not constraining the `SearchViewController` view at all in your `ViewController` view

```swift
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    searchViewController.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
    searchViewController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
    searchViewController.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
    searchViewController.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
])
```

And your final `ViewController` implementation should look like this:

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let searchViewController = SearchViewController()
        addChild(searchViewController)
        searchViewController.didMove(toParent: self)
        view.addSubview(searchViewController.view)
        searchViewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            searchViewController.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            searchViewController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            searchViewController.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            searchViewController.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
        ])
    }
    
}
```

Another issue is that you are using old API for setting the constraints inside the `SearchViewController`. The documentation of [addConstraint](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622523-addconstraint) says:

> When developing for iOS 8.0 or later, set the constraint’s isActive property to true instead of calling the addConstraint method directly. The isActive property automatically adds and removes the constraint from the correct view.

You can use the [activate(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutconstraint/1526955-activate) static function on `NSLayoutConstraint` to activate them at once.

```swift
view.addSubview(textField)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    textField.leadingAnchor
        .constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
    textField.topAnchor
        .constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0),
    textField.trailingAnchor
        .constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0),
])
```

Resources:

- Official Documentation: [Implementing a Container View Controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html)
- Article by John Sundell: [Child View Controllers](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/basics/child-view-controllers/)
- Article by Antoine v.d. SwiftLee [Auto Layout in Swift: Writing constraints programmatically](https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/auto-layout-programmatically/)

Comment: Hey! Your code seems to work when I only set the background color. However, when I use it with a UITextField, it doesn't  work. It shows a black screen. Here's the error: "[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
 Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
 Try this: 
  (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
  (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it."

Comment: Okay, I'm waiting.

Comment: Oh yeah! It works like a charm. Thank you a lot! Can you please tell me what does translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints do before I mark your answer?

Comment: the TLDR is `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` when set to `false` will make your view compatible with auto layout. When set to true, it will use frame-based layout. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47801753/8160613).

Comment: What is viewController in addChild(viewController) ?

Comment: @ulmas it was a typo, I meant `searchViewController`. Thanks for pointing that out