# Section header title lost when customize the section header view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In my code I use below code to set the section header title of the tableview. And it works well.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int)
    -> String? {
        //return self.adHeaders[section]
        return self.headers[section]
}
```

I want to customize the background color of the header, so I insert below code before the above code.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerView = UIView()
    headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 232/255.0, green: 237/255.0, blue: 242/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    return headerView
}
```

As a result, the background color changes, while the title text lost.

Comment: And you may even look into [Is it possible to obtain a dynamic table view section header height using Auto Layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29462331/3687801)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you implement `viewForHeaderInSection`, `titleForHeaderInSection` isn’t called at all. So you need to set the title of your header view in `viewForHeaderInSection`. You probably need to create a UILabel.

You must also implement `heightForHeaderInSection`.

Comment: Thank you. It works. As I don't have much experience of IOS developing. I just want to know is it the proper way to customize the header view.

Comment: Yes, a custom header is the way to customize.