# viewForHeaderInSection not getting called on reloadData

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitableviewsectionheader

viewForHeaderInSection is not getting called on reloadData. How ever it is getting called first time when the view is loaded. Very strange. Any help?I've implemented the below delegate methods.

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 0;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1500.0f;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return  UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}

-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {}
```

Comment: Also the tableView outlet, delegate and datasource are correctly connected.

Comment: Edit your question with that code and format it Also the additional informations. It's not really readable in comments, and can be missed while it's important information.

Comment: I have edited the question, please check.

Comment: Please show more context for this code.

Comment: For me work just fine, maybe the issue is in other part of your code.

Comment: On reload all other methods are getting called except the viewForHeader.

Comment: I don't see there's any executable code in your viewForHeaderInSection(). Did you try adding NSLog() statement?

Comment: I didn't paste the implementation of this method here.

Answer (score 0):

Your `heightForHeaderInSection` probably return `0` because `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` does not work. In order to make `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` work you have to set all left, right, bottom, and top constraints relative to cell container view.

Comment: I can't return 10. The seize is calculated based on constraints. So I have to return UITableViewAutomaticDimension.

Comment: OK, in that case You need to implement `self.tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight` https://stackoverflow.com/a/29763200/1155354

Comment: then why does it works first time when the view is loaded and does not work when I explicitly call reloadData?