# Swift Autolayout headerview in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, autolayout

I'm trying to create a view that has some labels and a UITableView.
First of all i tried to create a UIView => UIScrollview => UIView + UITableView
After reading a lot i experienced problems with scrolls, 1 from the UIScrollView and 1 from the UITableView, so i decided to switch to the suggested approach of having: UIView => UITableView with headerview

Scroll works fine but now i have problems with Autolayout.

The header view have 2 labels. "LeftLabel" and "RightLabel". The RightLabel should have dynamic height and >= 21

In code i tried to add a text that won't fit in 1 line and with autolaout label should expand and use 2 o 3 lines to fit the text.

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

In this screenshot is shown only 1 line.
Constraints are set as:
[image: Autolayout]

I uploaded the demo proyect to github: https://github.com/Miguel86/UIViewAutolayoutExample/
Scroll works fine, but autolayout of the "headerview" not.

Any suggestion of where could be the problem?

[UPDATE]
Solved using the approach explained in:
https://github.com/aunnnn/TableHeaderViewWithAutoLayout

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, problem is that RightLabel isn't going to multiple lines? If so: go into storyboard, select the headerview and drag it down so it's Height is longer. I think there just wasn't enough room in the cell for the label to go to 2 lines.

Comment: Yes, but that is why i want to use autolayout. And if the text don't fit in 3 lines...

Comment: Did you do what I said? I ran your project and it went on more than 3 lines. FYI - autolayout does not dynamically change the height of the header/cell. That is set when the tableview loads.

Comment: Yes i tested, i don't want in design more height, obviously if by default its height is enough to have 2 lines will work, but if the text requires 3 lines will fail another time.

Answer (score 0):

Try Setting Lines to “0” and Line Breaks To “word wrap”

Comment: Tested but doesn't work, you will only see 1 line with "This is a long text that won't fit" but the rest of the string is not displayed.

Comment: I think the problem is not the label but the height of your header view. Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29462331/is-it-possible-to-obtain-a-dynamic-table-view-section-header-height-using-auto-l

Comment: Thanks @Aakash verma. finally i solved with this: https://github.com/aunnnn/TableHeaderViewWithAutoLayout