# Multi-line UILabel in TableView header

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel, multiline

How can I achieve multi-line UILabel inside a UITableView header (not to be confused with view for header in section), with top,left,bottom and right anchors using autolayout programatically ?[click here for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWx7n.png)

The grey cells are the table view cells. Above the cells, I need the table view header with the support for multiple lines for both the UILabel [the total area in white background will be the tableview header].

Currently, my UILabel does not go beyond a single line (i have tried setting number of lines property to 0 for multi-line as well).

Comment: Please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29462331/is-it-possible-to-obtain-a-dynamic-table-view-section-header-height-using-auto-l

Comment: Did t’you tried to set number of lines to 3 or 4. This is maximum number of line.

Comment: Please note : I am looking for a solution for tableViewHeader https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614904-tableheaderview and not a view for header in section. The viewForHeader in section reloads a tableview everytime we scroll up, but that is not the case for tableHeaderView